# DataGridView column width settings ignored?

Tags: c#

I'm using the designer in Visual C# Express to set the column widths. One column has a fixed width, the other two are auto fill. However, after I populate the grid...

```
document = XDocument.Load(databasepath);
releases_dataGridView.DataSource = document;

//query

releases_dataGridView.DataSource = q.ToList();
```

...these width settings are apparently gone and default width values are used instead. It seems that the set column widths are ignored or switched back.

Comment: What does your XML look like for the gridview control.. you should be looking at HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" under ListView in the xml

Comment: There's also a setting for `DataGridViews` called `AutoSizeColumnMode`, make sure it's set to None.